# calling a javascript function after Updating the div

Tags: javascript

I have an div tag like this

I am updating the div as shown below using prototype

```
 $('dateRange').update(dateData[xmin] + ' - ' + dateData[xmax]);
```

My question is after Updating the div , is it possibe to call a function ??

I have search div event handlers , but nothing is working .

could anybody please help .

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use this function:

`$.fn.andThen = function(callback) { callback.call(this); return this; }`

So you would do:

```
$('dateRange').update(dateData[xmin] + ' - ' + dateData[xmax]).andThen(function() { alert("Updated"); });
```

Although I'd just call the function after I've updated the div, unless you're doing some `$.ajax` call or something asynchronous.

Comment: Hi james , could you please tell me how this works , because its not working for me

Comment: Check out this, http://jsfiddle.net/jbrooksuk/nDZex/ I replaced your "update" with `html()` for a POF :)

Answer (score 0):

Call it right after your update statement. it's not asynchronous I assume.